# How can I convert a input string into dictionary for each rows of a column in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a column values of a dataframe where I am receiving a string input like below where startIndex is the index of beginning of each character, end index is the end of occurrence of that character in the string and flag is the character itself.

```
    +---+------------------+
    | id|    Values        |
    +---+------------------+
    |01 |  AABBBAA         |
    |02 |  SSSAAAA         |
    +---+------------------+
```

Now I want to convert the string into dictionary for each rows as depicted below:

```
    +---+--------------------+
    | id|    Values          |
    +---+--------------------+
    |01 |  [{"startIndex":0, |
    |   |    "endIndex" : 1, | 
    |   |    "flag" : A },   |
    |   |   {"startIndex":2, |
    |   |    "endIndex" : 4, |
    |   |    "flag" : B },   |
    |   |   {"startIndex":5, |
    |   |    "endIndex" : 6, |
    |   |    "flag" : A }]   |
    |02 |  [{"startIndex":0, |
    |   |    "endIndex" : 2, |
    |   |    "flag" : S },   |
    |   |   {"startIndex":3, |
    |   |    "endIndex" : 6, |
    |   |    "flag" : A }]   |
    +---+--------------------+-
```

I have the pseudo code to frame the dictionary but not sure how to apply it 
to all the rows at one go without using loops. Also the problem with such
approach is only the last framed dictionary is getting overwritten in all the rows

```
        import re
        x = "aaabbbbccaa"
        xs = re.findall(r"((.)\2*)", x)
        print(xs)
        start = 0
        output = '' 
        for item in xs:
            end = start + (len(item[0])-1)
            startIndex = start
            endIndex = end
            qualityFlag = item[1]
            print(startIndex, endIndex, qualityFlag)
            start = end+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **[udf()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf)** to wrap up the code logic and **[to_json()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_json)** to convert the array of structs into string:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, to_json
import re

df = spark.createDataFrame([
      ('01', 'AABBBAA')
    , ('02', 'SSSAAAA')
  ] , ['id', 'Values']
)

# argument `x` is a StringType() over the udf function
# return `row` as a list of dicts
@udf('array<struct<startIndex:long,endIndex:long,flag:string>>')
def set_fields(x):
    row = []
    for m in re.finditer(r'(.)\1*', x):
        row.append({
            'startIndex': m.start()
          , 'endIndex': m.end()-1
          , 'flag': m.group(1)
        })
    return row

df.select('id', to_json(set_fields('Values')).alias('Values')).show(truncate=False)
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |Values                                                                                                                      |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|01 |[{"startIndex":0,"endIndex":1,"flag":"A"},{"startIndex":2,"endIndex":4,"flag":"B"},{"startIndex":5,"endIndex":6,"flag":"A"}]|
|02 |[{"startIndex":0,"endIndex":2,"flag":"S"},{"startIndex":3,"endIndex":6,"flag":"A"}]                                         |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your solution is working in my case however when I am converting the dataframe into a json file I am getting something like this 
"[{\"startIndex\":1,\"endIndex\":48,\"qualityFlag\":\"A\"}]"
The whole array is coming as string and backslash before every inverted quote.
Any idea how I can get around it.

Comment: @Saikat, the field is already in JSON format, if you want to keep them as an ArrayType, then just adjust `to_json(set_fields('Values')).alias('Values')` to `set_fields('Values').alias('Values')`. after that, your export to json should get what you want.

Comment: my bad. Thanks a lot